# Ap Stats Need Help on Assessing Normality

Tags: self-study, normality-assumption

> Grey Kangaroos are large, social marsupials, indigenous to Australia. The Eastern Greys are a light grayish brown, while the Western Grey is a copper brown color. As part of a study of the development of these creatures, biologists have measured various aspects of their skeletal structure. A sample of 148 palate widths was taken from skeletal remains and the data is presented in the stem-and-leaf plot below. The distributions of skeletal measures are generally thought to be approximately normal, which is consistent with the stem-and-leaf plot for this sample. The display uses five lines for each stem. Thus, "2t|" is the stem for palate widths of 22 and 23, "2f|" for 24 and 25, "2s|" for 26 and 27, and so on. (The "t" then stands for leaves that are twos and threes, the "f" for leaves of fours and fives, etc.) The mean palate width of this sample is 2.6 cm, and the standard deviation is 0.3 cm.

```
Palate Width – Grey Kangaroos
       1|0 =  1  cm   N =  124
              1.|
              1t|
              1f|
              1s|77
              1*|89
              2.|01111111111
              2t|222222222223333333333333
              2f|444444444444444455555555555555
              2s|6666666666667777777
              2*|88888888888889999999999999
              3.|0000011
              3t|223
              3f|
              3s|
              3*|
```

> Assess the normality of the data as it pertains to the empirical rule. Be sure to show your calculations and thinking.

I am honestly not sure how to even start this or do this and was wondering if I could get some pointers or help

Comment: All I was told was to access the normality I would have to use either of three methods that is the empirical rule, looking at the histogram visually, and creating a normal probability plot, but how does the empirical rule work I'm not sure. Like what do I do?

Comment: I don't see anything about looking at histograms or creating probability plots in the question. Presumably you were given the empirical rule in your materials or it was discussed in class. Try Googling it.

Comment: I understand that part Im just confused about the data like what does 3* mean or 3t or is 2t | 2 just 22? Im not able to understand the stem and leaf plot.

Comment: That is explained in the text of the question. It says, `Thus, "2t|" is the stem for palate widths of 22 and 23`. The numbers to the right of the vertical bar (pipe) `|` indicate a value in the original dataset. If such a number is repeated, that value exists more than once in the original dataset, thus n repeats means that value shows up n times in the dataset.

Comment: There are many things wrong in the question: (+) The plot has extraneous stem portions (bad software!). (+) The mean clearly is not 2.6 (it is 2.5); this is important for applying the "empirical rule" (likely the [68-95-99.7 rule](http://tinyurl.com/n4ca9lh). (+) It lacks standard useful information such as leaf counts for each stem (+). It is an order of magnitude wrong in reporting the values; *e.g.*, the `2t` stem contains values of $2.2$ and $2.3$ cm, not "22 and 23" as claimed. (+) It provides contradictory counts ("148 palate widths" in the text are represented by `N = 124` in the plot).

Comment: Ohhhh I'm sorry posted the wrong question the actual one is: Comment on the normality of the data based upon the stem plot